# How much data should be stored in a single realm file

Tags: ios, realm

In my app data would be generated by user.

- Each user would on an average create an average of 4-5 entries per day.
- Eventually there would be 1000s of users storing data.

Now, for storage at the Realm Object Server, I see following options:

- Create a separate realm file for each user.
- Create a single realm file which would contain data of all the users.
- Create few large realm files (like for example one realm for every 100 users) based on some user grouping.

Would appreciate having some light on which approach would be better?

Comment: While there is an answer, the correct answer would depend on the use case; if users need the ability to see *all* of the data or query for data entered by another user, then a single file would be a solution. On the other hand if users data is discreet then it would make more sense to have a Realm per user. Providing more information in the question would help future readers understand the use.

Comment: User data is discreet.. One user's data will never be visible to other user.. I am going ahead with one realm per user..

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely have a single Realm file **per user**. The Realm Object Server is designed to handle this nicely.

You will want each user to authenticate (see [this documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#authentication)) and once they do, their own Realm will be created on the server. Any changes they make in your client apps will sync to all devices they authenticate with.

If you tried to combine multiple users in a single Realm, then all those users would see other users' data when they query for objects. That probably isn't what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of having multiple users in a single realm by using the partial sync feature. However, that does not seem to be stable at the moment (People have reported multiple problems/unsupported features with that feature as of now).. So probably best way would be going ahead with separate realms for each user.